# Simple php jump list from text file

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying make a simple drop down jump list from a text file... The text file would look like this:

```
websitename1 http:// websitename1.com
websitename2 http:// websitename2.com
websitename3 http:// websitename3.com
```

I can't find a script that will read the text file and only display column 1, and then "jump" to the related column 2 URL when selected.  I've found a lot of examples of how to populate a dropdown list using PHP — but non of them make the "jump" (on click action) once selected.

Comment: no idea what *make the " jump"* means

Comment: I assume you are trying to make a navigation menu. If so, it's not the PHP that will make it "jump", you will need to use Javascript to do that. Separate the problem into 2. Make an html page that behaves how you want, then write PHP to generate that page.

Comment: Sorry - I mean link - I assume they call it a jump menu because you don't have to click a Submit button to activate the link...

Comment: That's because they are using javascript for the onchange event of the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modified 08-20-13** - Added Blank Select Options and JS Function

To avoid unnecessary regex methods, you should probably use a .csv format instead of .txt. It stands for comma-separated values, and it will allow you to put website names with spaces without any tricky string manipulation. For example, your csv could look like this:

```
News,
Website Name 1,http://websitename1.com
Website Name 2,http://websitename2.com
Website Name 3,http://websitename3.com
Events,
Website Name 4,http://websitename4.com
Website Name 5,http://websitename5.com
Website Name 6,http://websitename6.com
```

And a quick little snippet could go something like this:

```
<select id="myselect" onchange="changePage( this.value );">

    <option value="" selected>Select Website...</option>

    <?php if( ( $file = fopen( 'websites.csv', "r" ) ) !== FALSE ): ?>

        <?php while( ( $row = fgetcsv( $file, 0, ',' ) ) !== FALSE ): ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

</select>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function changePage( url )
    {
        if( url !== '' )
        {
            window.open( url, '_blank' );
        }
    }
</script>
```

Just a thought, a jump list of 200 items may be quite large. In any case, the main line of code that makes this "jump" would be:

```
window.open = ( url, '_blank' );
```

This passes the value of the dropdown option to the window location, and will take the user to the selected page.

**A Word Of Warning**

If you require to put a comma in the website name or url for some reason, you'll need to enclose it in the csv. Luckily, fgetcsv allows you to optionally enclose fields with double-quotes by default. Example:

```
"Website, Name 4",http://websitename4.com
```

Will output `Website, Name 4` when the name variable is printed, and it won't erroneously think that `Name 4` is the next field over.

**Notes:**

- As the OP mentioned in the comments, the file extension does not have to be .csv, I have done so here to be consistent with proper conventions, however it does have to follow the same text format. I gave my file several different extensions (.wmv, .php, .jpg) and all of them seem to read the same. It's best just to call the file what it is, and also as pointed out below, .csv data will open with Excel. Use the Data Import from Text File method on a new workbook, you'll be able to make sure Excel doesn't auto-correct your columns and screw up your data by setting column data types through the import wizard.
- As Fred brought up, in the code `window.open( this.value, '_blank' )` you can change `'_blank'` to `'_self'` to load the new location on the same page.
  **Javascript open() reference:** http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

**Classes and the Like:**

If you wanted to give some class to your drop-downs, you can also add another column to your .csv for class name, and change how it echos a little. Your csv could look something like this:

```
News,,jump-title
Website Name 1,http://websitename1.com,jump-link
Website Name 2,http://websitename2.com,jump-link
Website Name 3,http://websitename3.com,jump-link
Events,,jump-title
Website Name 4,http://websitename4.com,jump-link
Website Name 5,http://websitename5.com,jump-link
Website Name 6,http://websitename6.com,jump-link
```

So now we have 3 fields, Name, Url, Class

And now modify the following line

**From:**

```
<option value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>
```

**To:**

```
<option value="<?php echo $row[1]; ?>" class="<?php echo $row[2]; ?>"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></option>
```

This way you can add a little bit of text formatting using CSS classes so your users can tell the difference visually between a link and a title.

Comment: wow - have been searching for 48 hours for this : ) ... is it too much to ask where I can insert a "target=_blank" to make the link start a separate session?

Comment: Great job Jason. However might I suggest you add `Select from menu` on top of `Website Name 1,http://websitename1.com` - that way if someone wants to visit the first site like the way you have it now, they won't be able to go to it, unless they highlight it and click on it again.

Comment: @user2680413 See my comment above this. Just add `Select from menu` for example on top, with nothing else.

Comment: Thank you Fred - will do! One note for future readers, Jason's code works with the text file as well...

Comment: @user2680413 Check my updated code, I've changed the `onchange=` value to `window.open( this.value, '_blank' )`

Comment: @user2680413 Added note: If you don't want links to open in a new window, change `'_blank'` to `'_top'` or `'_self'` or `'_parent'` depending on how you want your links to open as.

Comment: Thank you Jason - Fred et.al.  Drinks are on me next time!!! and the next round on all the future people this helps!!! Thank you again!

Comment: @user2680413 You're very much welcome. Glad I could be of help also, cheers ;-)

Comment: @user2680413 You know what to do next (wink)

Comment: @user2680413 Not a problem, I lurk around SE looking to help people just like you ;D. Don't forget to select your accepted answer if it fulfills your question, and don't hesitate to ask if I forget anything.

Comment: done - took me a second to find the "accept" button ... yes I am new and very impressed with this community already - I have a lot more questions where that came from : ) thank you again

Comment: @Jason *"the file extension does not have to be .csv"* --- I think it's rather a good file extension to use because the `.csv` file can be used in Excel and administered from there.

Comment: Hey guys - one more question... I am using a text file - how can I make section Headers/Titles/Separators with-in the list that are not linked... For example: I simply want the first option to be "News", but a click on "News" takes you to a page not found - I just want it to be a title and not linked to anything... I tried <select ="news"... doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Check out my edits, I think that's where you were going.

Comment: Yes Sir! that's what I was looking for! : ) ... Can you think of a way to not highlight the titles or spaces (created with only a comma) on rollover?

Comment: Most of the form elements are system/browser rendered, while I have looked around for a solution, I haven't found one that really works. Most solutions typically opt for replacing the `<select><option>` tags with `<ul><li>` tags and use CSS and Javascript to replace the standard dropdown. Look around for a tutorial on making a dropdown from html list elements.

Comment: Jason, is there any reason why I shouldn't be able to substitute "site, http ://" with "link, file://///" - I have my browser configured to open Windows Explore from "file://///" but it won't open it from your script.. any ideas? Otherwise the script is working perfectly!